# Better regex to get matching groups from html text?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text which will contain plain text with html span tags and I need to extract matching groups from that text.

Sample Text:

```
<p>This is post 
  <span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='#' data-channel-tag='true'>
   <span data-value='CR345sdfqDdjPuEbsAQ=='>newpost</span></span>
  &nbsp; with intention to make 
  <span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='#' data-channel-tag='true'>
   <span data-value='CRsdf345DdjPuEbsAQ=='>newchannel</span></span>
   &nbsp; and see how 
  <span class='atwho-inserted' data-atwho-at-query='#' data-channel-tag='true'>
  <span data-value='Ce3DzasdfdqqDdjPuEbsAQ=='>textforthis</span></span>
  &nbsp; gets genrated.
</p>
```

Now what I want to extract from this is `newpost,newchannel,textforthis` in group match at server side regex.

What I tried is as below,

`New Regex("<span [^>]*?data-value=[\\""|']{1,2}[^""']*[\\""|']>(?<hashtag>[^""<\/]+)<\/span>", RegexOptions.Compiled)`

Which works great and gives me the groups I require. But I am not good at writing regex and was thinking that can I optimize this regex ?

[Here is the RegExr link](https://regexr.com/403ce)

Comment: How is this too broad ? I specifically mentioned I need to optimize my currently written regex. At least comment here to know more and then tag it as too broad.

Comment: You're not good at regex, that's fine. But you shouldn't use regex for this.

Comment: Ya I know but this is part of very old and much more complicated system that I can not have control and time to rewrite. The current format of text has been changed and I am just trying to update that part by replacing old regex with new one.

Comment: try `<span(?=.*'>(\S+?)<).*<\/span>` https://regex101.com/r/smvXz6/3

Comment: @ran_0315 Can you try with the text in link within question from RegExr because the text which I posted is formatted here (to show in multi line instead of single line) and original post may not have newlines between spans.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/smvXz6/4

Comment: Do you just need the capturing group? Or you also need to select the whole `span`. How do you differentiate the needed `spans` within other `spans`? Is that because the needed `spans` have `data-value`?

Comment: @Julio yes a needed span has the `data-value` and I just need capturing groups.

Comment: Your regexr link uses a different regex compared to the one on your question. Which one should We compare against?

Comment: Also, when talking about optimize, what do you want? A 'faster' regex even if it is uglier? Or a simpler, easy-to-read regex? What's your preferred target? Speed or *readingness*?

Comment: @Julio I would prefer speed over readingness because this will be processing lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to optimize the regex, you have several options. Flexibility will come at a prize.

These four regexes have less steps than the 2 regexes you provided (3785 and 1296)

1. If you can be sure that the `spans` you want to fetch just have the `data-value` attribute an no other one, you may use: `<span data-value[^>]+>(?<hashtag>[^\s<]+)` See **[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8HS6F/3)**. This is the fastest solution (**279 steps**) I could figure out. However, if a `span` has some additional attribute before the `data-value`, It will fail
2. [This](https://regex101.com/r/k8HS6F/4) (`<span (?>[^>d]*)data-value[^>]+>(?<hashtag>[^\s<]+)`) is similar in concept to case 1. It is not much slower (**342 steps**) and can work with attributes before `data-value` as long as there is no a `d` letter on them
3. [This](https://regex101.com/r/k8HS6F/2) (`<span (?>(?>[^>d]*)(?(?=data-value)[^>]+|d))*>(?<hashtag>[^\s<]+)`) will work for any case, even if you find some attributes before `data-value`. It is **903 steps**
4. [This](https://regex101.com/r/k8HS6F/5) (`<span [^>]*?data-value[^>]+>(?<hashtag>[^\s<]+)`) will also work for any case. It is easier to read, but it costs some more (**1146 steps**)

Also, I would consider the number of steps just an starting point or a guide. In the end, I would rely on some benchmarks to decide.